# PDE: Guess non-polynomial solution of $\Delta u=\frac{\delta^2u}{\delta x^2}-\frac{\delta^2u}{\delta y^2}=0$

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations

I need to verify that the function $$u(x,y)=a\cdot ln(x^2 + y^2)$$ is a solution of the two-dimensional Laplace equation $$\Delta u=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2} \qquad (1)$$ and later I have to use the result to guess one non-polynomial (non-trivial) solution of the equation $$\Delta u=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=0 \qquad (2)$$ and verify my result. 
I did first part of the problem where I calulated first and second derivative of u and inserted it into equation. Later I made a guess that the solution for (2) can be: $$u(x,y)=a\cdot ln(x^2 - y^2) \qquad (3)$$ and I calulcated derivaties and so on. My question is, is my guess correct?

Comment: The standard symbol for a partial derivative is $\partial$, not $\delta$.

Comment: Yes, but I can guarantee you that they know that already, are new to using LaTeX, and simply guessed that the command was "\delta" since after all  the standard pronunciation for $\partial$ is 'del' and it is often referred to as a delta.

Comment: note: $a\ln (\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$  solves Laplace's

Answer (score 1):

Your guess

$$u(x,y)=a\cdot ln(x^2 - y^2)  $$

does  satisfy the $$\frac {\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=0  $$

Thus your guess is as good as gold.

Comment: are there any rules for the guesses? How to choose them correctly?

Comment: I was about to comment the mistake before you edited it. The guess can be easily explained to work by substituting $y$ by $iy$ in the Laplace equation and in its solution.

Comment: Your guess was correct. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I verified it and the solution was ok. The only thing which made me doubt was that in the task was mentioned that solution is non-polynomial and non-trivial. I made a guess base on the first solution that was given to the first equation, that's why I want to verify it.

Comment: @Vid The  partial differential equation is a simple form of wave equation which could be solved by separation of variables or by d'Alembert's method. For just guessing, you did fine.

Answer (score -1):

The function $$u(x,y)=a\cdot ln(x^2 - y^2)$$ is a solution of the equation $(2)$, as you successfully guessed. 
$$\Delta u=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=0 \qquad (2)$$

Note that a lot of solutions can be found on the general form :
$$u(x,y)=f(x+y)+g(x-y)$$
with any differentiable functions $f$ and $g$.

For example, taking $\quad \begin{cases}f(x+y)=a\:\ln(x+y) \\g(x-y)=a\:\ln(x-y) \end{cases}\quad $
$$u(x,y)=a\:\ln(x+y)+a\:\ln(x-y)=a\ln((x+y)(x-y))=a\ln(x^2-y^2)$$
is solution of Eq.$(2)$.

But other functions of $(x^2-y^2)$ are not solution of Eq.$(2)$.

Other example, with $f(x+y)=\sin(x+y)$ and $g(x-y)=\sin(x-y)$ we obtain $u(x,y)=2\cos(x)\sin(y)$ which is solution of Eq.$(2)$.

One can found many other solutions with other functions $f$ and $g$ , even with $f\neq g$, including a lot of polynomial solutions in case of polynomial functions $f$ and $g$.